# docker build inline command fails with process substitution part

Tags: docker, process-substitution

I am wondering why this docker build command fails:

```
docker build -t inline_img -f <(cat
`FROM node:12`
) .

[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from 11                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 55B                                        0.0s
 => CANCELED [internal] load .dockerignore                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context:                                               0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build definition from 11:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: failed to xattr /dev/fd/11: operation not permitted
```

is this a perms issue?

Comment: same error with a one-liner: `docker build -t inline_img:latest -f <(cat \`FROM node:12\`) .`

Comment: and same with: `docker build -t inline_img:latest -f <(echo 'FROM node:12') .`